# Rename [android-wear] to [wear-os]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Android Wear has been renamed Wear OS. Can [android-wear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-wear) be renamed [wear-os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wear-os), and perhaps also set as a synonym for the new tag?

Source: https://www.blog.google/products/wear-os/android-wear-its-time-new-name/

> As our technology and partnerships have evolved, so have our users. In 2017, one out of three new Android Wear watch owners also used an iPhone. So as the watch industry gears up for another Baselworld next week, we’re announcing a new name that better reflects our technology, vision, and most important of all—the people who wear our watches. We’re now Wear OS by Google, a wearables operating system for everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[android-wear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-wear) and [wearos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wearos) are now synonyms of [wear-os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wear-os)

All questions have been moved accordingly.

Tag wiki and Tag info has been copied and updated, including link redirects.